mix-blend-mode: difference with z-index won't work as expected on Safari
I'm developing a portfolio website with some blurred NavBar at the top. It has a z-index of 50 so it stays on top of other elements: 
Or it looks like this if the user hasn't scrolled yet: 
But on Safari, probably because of it's z-index is higher then the other elements and it can't "mix the difference" with no other element on its index, it looks like this:
 (You can see the texts if you look hard enough.)

What can I do to solve this? I really like this effect so I don't want to give up on that. Here are the codes:
NavBar:

  <nav
    class="w-full px-2 sm:px-4 py-2 sm:py-4 flex justify-evenly items-center bg-transparent text-2xl sm:text-3xl fixed top-0 z-50 mix-blend-difference backdrop-blur-sm"
  >
    <ul class="flex space-x-4 sm:space-x-8 text-white">
      <li hover>
        <a href="#">{{ $t('routes.home') }}</a>
      </li>
      <li hover>
        <a href="#about-me">{{ $t('routes.about') }}</a>
      </li>
      <li hover>
        <a href="#work">{{ $t('routes.work') }}</a>
      </li>
      <li hover>
        <a href="#blog">{{ $t('routes.blog') }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

Layout:
  <div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
    <AppNavbar /> <!-- Here is the Navbar -->
    <div class="flex-1 p-6">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <AppFooter class="z-40 bg-background" />
    <ScrollHint class="z-40" />
    <FloatingButtons class="z-40" />
  </div>

I'm using Tailwind but you can provide solutions with pure CSS.
I have tried changing the z-index of the elements to an equal number, and it seems working properly but that's not I want. NavBar must stay-on-top to follow the user scroll.
